# OpenCV - Identifying particular object in image using Java

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, feature-extraction, orb

I'm developing an opencv application in java where I need to detect the different marks on the product.[***I have attached the input image below***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONOBx.jpg)
In that image I need to identify the non veg mark.

Since i'm new to it, I need help to know which concepts can be used for it.
I need to identify [***these marks***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gy4wI.png) on the input images

Comment: You could attempt **template matching** for this problem. Resize the 'non-veg' image logo to variable sizes and run a moving window over the source image (food image). Check where exactly the resized logo matches on the source image.

Comment: the "veg & non-veg logo" will sometimes have light variations in color.

Comment: ok first check if the template (logo) matches the image for a particular size. If it does then you have decide whether it is 'green' or 'red'. You can give a range for red and green using the HSV color space!

Comment: I'm not able to achieve it successfully. can u do up a small code for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After quite a struggle I was able to come up with a rough solution.

***First***, I separated the **veg** and **non-veg** labels.

[image]  & [image]

Now in order to get the perfect fit of the **non-veg** label over the image I resized it to a particular level:

```
small = cv2.resize(nveg, (0,0), fx=0.12, fy=0.12)
```

[image]

Now I performed ***Template matching*** as I stated in the comments' section. To learn more about this topic [VISIT THIS PAGE](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/dc6/tutorial_py_template_matching.html).

Using it I obtained the '*maximum probable location*' of the non-veg label in the image.

```
res = cv2.matchTemplate(food, small, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(res)
```

In the following image pay attention to the bright spot in the position of the non-veg mark:

[image]

Now using the `max_loc` variable, I added the tuple values to the size of the resized non-veg label and framed it with a rectangle as in the following:

[image]

You can see the black spot on the non-veg mark when I labelled it using `max_loc`:

[image]

Hope this helped. :)

Comment: In this answer I explicitly resized the non-veg mark by trial- and-error. An even better solution is to automate the `resize` function such that the best fit is obtained. In this way it can be run for several images. :)

Comment: As I mentioned in my previous comment, you have to resize the non-veg template so as to get the best match for different images.

Comment: Actually the wrong matches cannot be found because there won't be any correlation